# How did the Cutty Wren come to be the national anthem of Tristan da Cunha?

Tags: history-of-literature, cultural-context, oral-tradition

["The Cutty Wren"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutty_Wren), a traditional English folk song, is the "territorial song" (like national anthem for a British Overseas Territory?) of [Tristan da Cunha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_da_Cunha), one of the remotest islands on earth with around 250 inhabitants.

**Why is this?** Was there a cultural connection between this particular song and the island or its settlers? I tried to search online, but only found the information that it *is* the territorial song there, nothing about *why*.